Why is the LIKE clause not working in my native SQL query with Spring Data JPA?
I'm trying to implement a search feature in my Spring Boot application using a native SQL query to find products by name. My query looks like this:
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM product_info_table WHERE product_name LIKE %:prodName%", nativeQuery = true)
List<Product> findByProdName(@Param("prodName") String prodName, PageRequest pageable);

However, I'm getting the following error message:

MySQL: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT * FROM product_info_table WHERE product_name LIKE %:prodName%'

I understand that the error is related to the syntax of the LIKE clause. Do I need to make some changes to the query or the way I'm passing the parameter?
I have the following JPQL query that retrieves students by name using the LIKE operator:
@Query("SELECT st FROM Student st WHERE st.studName LIKE %:name%")
List<Student> findAllByName(@Param("name") String studName);

I want to create a native SQL query that behaves in the same way.

I linked to an answer that explains this in the context of PHP, but the answer is the same for Java or any other language.
